# A question about Hatcher Algebraic Topology, Proposition 3.25

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have some questions when reading Hatcher's textbook on the "orientation in homology".

According to the **proposition 3.25**,

> If $M$ is $connected$, then $M$ is orientable iff $\widetilde{M}$ has two
> components (or, according to [the lecture](https://youtu.be/XpmG1hS9nZs?t=4521), $\widetilde{M}$ has two copies of cover)

**I wonder that** $connctedness$ **is crucial condition on the given proposition.** To begin with, the proof of proposition is going ;

> **Proof**.  If $M$ is $connected$, $\widetilde{M}$ has either one or two components since it is a two-sheeted covering space of $M$ ......

So, $connectedness$ is anyway referred during the proof. However, the author previously showed that every (topological) manifold $M$ has (an orientable) $two-sheeted ~covering~ space$ $\widetilde{M}$. In other words, two-sheeted covering $\widetilde{M}$ is always constructed if $M$ is just (topological) manifold

Or, Even if I consider the definition of [$component$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components) on the connected space , it is still doubtful for me that *connectedness* is essential condition, because, repeatedly saying, every (topological) manifold $M$ has (an orientable) $two-sheeted ~covering~ space$ $\widetilde{M}$.

Comment: Try thinking about some examples of non-connected manifolds and you will see the role of connectedness.

Comment: A two-sheeted covering of a non-connected space can have more than two components. You can generalize the theorem to say that if $M$ has $n$ components if and only if $\tilde{M}$ has $2n$ components, but this is not as useful than looking at everything component-by-component and breaks down for manifolds with infinitely many components.