# Why connectedness implies exactly two orientations?

Tags: algebraic-topology

[Continuously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404698/a-question-about-hatcher-algebraic-topology-proposition-3-25?noredirect=1#comment9214116_4404698), I have some questions when reading Hatcher's textbook on the "orientation in homology".

According to the **proposition 3.25**,

> If $M$ is $connected$, then $M$ is orientable iff $\widetilde{M}$ has two
> components.

Now, I am now stuck in ($\Longrightarrow$) part. According to the textbook,  "since $M$ is connected, $M$ has exactly two orinetation".... but I totally do not understand this part when considering the definition of "orientation" in Hacther's textbook : An **Orientation** is a function $M\to H_n(M|x), $ $x \mapsto \mu_x$, which satisfying a local consistency condition. But why is *two orientation* when *M* is connected?

For example, given a (connected) manifold $M=\mathbb{R}^2, $ a plane,  is given, and if I pick a point $x$, then I set a finite radius $r_x$ containing $x$, such that $H_n(M|B_x) \simeq H_n(M|x) \simeq H_n(M|x')$, where $x'\in B_x$, and $ B_x$ is an open ball with finite radius about $x$. If such local condition is satisfied, $M\to H_n(M|x), $ $x \mapsto \mu_x$ is a orientation. Anyway, *one* orienation is constructed.

However, following this method, It seems possible to construct more than two orientation : **whenever** picking a point $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, I set an open ball $B_y$ with radius $r_y$ which containing a point $y$ , **but not intersecting** to $B_x$ (i.e $B_x \cap B_y = \phi )$, such that $H_n(M|B_y) \simeq H_n(M|y) \simeq H_n(M|y')$, where $y'\in B_y$. From this local consistency condition, $M\to H_n(M|y), $ $y \mapsto \mu_y$ seems to be defined. Of course, $H_n(M|B_y) $ is **not** homeomorphic to $H_n(M|B_x)$ since intersection of each open ball is empty. Hence, more than two orientations, actually infinitely many orientations, will be constructed.

Clearly, such thought is clearly wrong. I may distort the definition of orientation, but I cannot find my flaw, even though repeating to read the definition of orientation.

Comment: You might find [my answer to a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/750252/are-there-surfaces-with-more-than-two-sides/750904#750904) to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an orientation on $M$, then $x\mapsto\mu_x$ is a function $M\rightarrow\widetilde{M}$, which, by the very definition of the topology of $\widetilde{M}$, becomes continuous and is clearly a section of the covering projection $\widetilde{M}\rightarrow M$. This is a two-sheeted covering and a two-sheeted covering of a connected space can have at most two continuous sections! This is a consequence of the fact that a section of a covering of a connected space is determined by its value at any single point, a consequence of the unique lifting property (sections are nothing but lifts of the identity).

The issue with your attempts is that for an orientation of $\mathbb{R}^2$, you have to pick a generator $\mu_x\in H_2(\mathbb{R}^2\mid x)$ for *every* $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$. But it's not possible to pick pairwise disjoint open balls $x\in B_x\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ for *every* $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$. In fact, let's assume you have chosen an orientation $(\mu_x)_{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ are two points and you have chosen disjoint balls $x\in B_x,y\in B_y$ as in the question. The issue is the following: you can find points $z_1,\dotsc,z_n\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and open balls $z_1\in B_1,\dotsc,z_n\in B_n$, for which the consistency condition is satisfied, such that $B_x$ intersects $B_1$, $B_1$ intersects $B_2$, etc. up to $B_{n-1}$ intersects $B_n$ and $B_n$ intersects $B_y$. This is a combination of the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, that the orientation satisfies local consistency and that open balls around any point form a neighborhood basis. I urge you to understand this pictorially. Now, $\mu_x$ determines $\mu_z$ for any $z\in B_x$ by local consistency, so in particular it determines $\mu_z$ for any $z\in B_x\cap B_1$ and this intersection is non-empty. But these in turn determine $\mu_z$ for any $z\in B_1$ by local consistency, so in particular they determine $\mu_z$ for any $z\in B_1\cap B_2$, which is non-empty by assumption. Rinse and repeat and we get that $\mu_x$ determines $\mu_y$, so you cannot choose them independently. In fact, this argument easily generalizes to show directly that an orientation on a connected manifold is determined by its value at any single point.